# Container will not float right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a pretty simple thing, getting a container to line up to the right side of another container. For some reason I am really struggling.

I made a very basic fiddle to show what I am trying to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lvoy1dtd/

I have tried adding

```
display: inline;
float: right;
```

to

```
.top_post_out {
    border: solid 1px #C0C0C0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 25px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
```

As well as making it `inline-block` and many other things, but it not lining up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/Lvoy1dtd/2/

Add "float: left" to your first container

```
rankingTableOut {
    border: solid 1px #C0C0C0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I didn't try that.

Comment: This may have all sorts of unintended side effects and is not the correct solution. You both should make yourself familiar with the (sometimes difficult) concept of floats.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display:inline-block;` to the `rankingTableOut` class instead of the `top_post_out`. Divs are by default block elements, which causes them to have a line break after them. So your next element is floating to the right of the *next* line, not the right of the current line as you wanted. The inline-block property will prevent the line break while preserving the width and height of your element.

Answer (score 0):

Floating elements need to be defined in your markup **prior to**, or **at the start of** the content that is supposed to "float around it". Just reordering your containers solves your problem, no additional CSS required.

```
<div class="top_post_out">
    <p>Make me right</p>
</div> 
<div class="rankingTableOut">
    <p>Make me left</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lvoy1dtd/3/

You should also read [Understanding floats](http://phrogz.net/CSS/understandingfloats.html).